# Pg Admin 3 not showing anything when i open it, what is wrong?

Tags: pgadmin

Just yesterday, I have managed to open PG admin 3 and get a panel on the left hand side with the server, database etc. A few hours ago, I opened PG admin and this comes up:

[image: .]

This is the first thing that comes up when I open the application. I honestly have no idea what is happening here and I cannot get to any of my databases, can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried registering or connecteing to any server?

Comment: No because I never had this issues before, I just opened it and got all my servers and databases there. I don't know how to connect to any server or anything like that, same with registering.